# Namespace constraint in template definition

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, template-specialization

I have to specialize a template function for all types in a given namespace `rofl`. Is a namespace constraint for a template type possible? I have the following in mind:

```
template<typename rofl::T>
MyClass::MyFunc() {
    impl = T::create();
}
```

Comment: " for all instances" - for all instances of what? Templates are specialised on types, not instances.

Comment: That's right. After a day of programming such mistakes may happen.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: AFAIK the namespace has no effect on the type which would make this impossible.  Kind of sounds like an XY problem though.  What is it that you need to achieve?

Comment: Part of the glory of templates is they will specialize as you need them. Are you wanting to make a file containing a pool of pre-specialized templates to reduce your executable or library size?

Comment: I want to hide two different implementations (each in its own namespace) in one interface. Both implementations use different methods to create their implementation instances, but these methods are similar accross all types in each namespace, for exaple: A::create() and B::buildObject().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a function template inside the namespace you want to specialize for, you can use argument dependent lookup.

```
struct Out{};

namespace ns
{
    struct In{};

    template <typename T>
    void ADL(const T&){} //Found via argument dependent lookup
}

template <class T, class U = decltype(ADL(std::declval<T>()))>
void func_impl(int) //Better match, only works if function ADL is found
{
    std::cout << "Specialized.\n";
}

template <class T>
void func_impl(...)
{
    std::cout << "Unspecialized.\n";
}

template <class T>
void func()
{
    func_impl<T>(0);
}
```

When you call `func` it will call the correct overload of the `func_impl`.

```
func<Out>(); //prints Unspecialized.
func<ns::In>(); //prints Specialized.
```